# Can you create a timer without the Timer component

Tags: vb.net, winforms, timer

I'm working on an application that requires a Timer to be running every 60 seconds to refresh the information on a 3270 mainframe.  I would like to not have any GUI with it but I can't seem to find a way to have a Timer work without the Tick event, would it be possible to always have a Timer running until the user closes the application without having the Timer component in the application?

Comment: Use a `System.Threading.Timer` instead.

Comment: You can also just spawn a new background thread with a while loop in it to put your work within and make it Sleep() for 60 seconds...essentially the same thing as a timer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Public Sub Wait(ByVal sec As Integer)
    sec = sec * 1000
    Dim sw As New Stopwatch
    sw.Start()
    Do Until sw.ElapsedMilliseconds >= sec
        Application.DoEvents()
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)
    Loop
    sw.Stop()
End Sub
```

Enjoy =)

Comment: +1 @Et1. More info can be found on Stopwatch here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx

Comment: Using Application.DoEvents is a bit dubious.  It's generally not recommended.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  You can use a [`System.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) (or a [`System.Threading.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx)), and create this manually in the code.

The designer is not required to use these timers.